# Specified cast is not valid. Linq DateTime

Tags: c#, linq

I have "Specified cast is not valid" error message in Linq when i am trying to execute the below query.

```
var query = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        where SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(a.Field<DateTime>("StartDate")), DateTime.Now) >= 0 
                        select a;
```

I have StartDate as '1997-10-01T00:00:00'. Can anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: Is the field actually stored as a `DateTime` object or a `string`?  Seems to me it's a string.

Comment: @Jodrell: surely if you are casting you cast and if you are parsing you parse. If you know that field is actually a datetime then just cast it to one. No point converting to a string just to parse it back to where you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I call shenanigans on your claim that the column is **stored** as a `DateTime`. I bet you're actually storing a *string representation* of a date in that column.

To demonstrate, here's a simple example with what exceptions you would get (if any).

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("AsString", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("AsDateTime", typeof(DateTime));
var now = DateTime.Now;
var row = dt.Rows.Add(now.ToString(), now);

row.Field<string>("AsString");     // this is fine
row.Field<string>("AsDateTime");   // InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'.
row.Field<DateTime>("AsString");   // InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
row.Field<DateTime>("AsDateTime"); // this is fine
DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("AsString")); // this is fine
```

So as you should be able to see, when attempting to read the field that is *stored* as a `string` but you try to access it as a `DateTime`, it throws the exception with the message you just described.

---

There's two ways you could fix it.

What I would recommend is to change the type on your column so it is for `DateTime` objects and actually store `DateTime` values.  No, a string representation will not work.  Then your query would work as you would expect it with no additional changes.

Otherwise, change your query so you're accessing the field using the correct type (a `string`), parse it back to a `DateTime` object and go from there.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var query =
    from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
    let startDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("StartDate"))
    where SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(
        TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(startDate),
        now) >= 0 
    select row;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if column is nullable. If So use `a.Field<DateTime?>("StartDate")` instead.

Answer (score -1):

not an exact response but :

```
var query = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where 
                a.StartDate > DateTime.Now
            select a;
```

should run (assuming s.StartDate is a DateTime)

Comment: Based on the usage, `dt` is a `DataTable` most likely.  You wouldn't be able to access the fields that way.