# "Specified cast is not valid" for Datetime C# lambda parsing

Tags: c#, lambda, casting, kendo-grid

While parsing through a DataTable object using Lambda, I am not getting what is wrong in the following code.

```
List<ApprovalPCNReportViewModel> report = GetApprovalPCNReport().AsEnumerable().Select(m => new ApprovalPCNReportViewModel()
        {
            PCNNotificationNumber = m.Field<String>("NotifiDocNumber"),
            CreatedDate = m.Field<DateTime>("CreatedDate"),
            EmailRecipients = m.Field<String>("EmailRecipients"),
            EmailSentDate = m.Field<DateTime>("EmailSentDate"),
            EmailOpenedDate = m.Field<DateTime>("EmailOpenedDate"),
            MailFrequency = m.Field<int>("MailFrequency"),
            ApprovedDate = m.Field<DateTime>("ApprovedDate"),
            ApprovedBy = m.Field<String>("ApprovedBy")
}).ToList();
```

DataTable binding -

```
public DataTable GetApprovalPCNReport()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("NotifiDocNumber");
        dt.Columns.Add("CreatedDate");
        dt.Columns.Add("EmailRecipients");
        dt.Columns.Add("EmailSentDate");
        dt.Columns.Add("EmailOpenedDate");
        dt.Columns.Add("MailFrequency");
        dt.Columns.Add("ApprovedDate");
        dt.Columns.Add("ApprovedBy");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["NotifiDocNumber"] = "Column1 - Row " + i;
            dr["CreatedDate"] = DateTime.Now;
            dr["EmailRecipients"] = "Column3 - Row " + i;
            dr["EmailSentDate"] = DateTime.Now;
            dr["EmailOpenedDate"] = DateTime.Now;
            dr["MailFrequency"] = i;
            dr["ApprovedDate"] = DateTime.Now;
            dr["ApprovedBy"] = "Column6 - Row " + i;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Here is the data -
[The DataTable values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me5en.png)
[image]

The view model(ApprovalPCNReportViewModel) -

```
public String PCNNotificationNumber { get; set; }
public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
public String EmailRecipients { get; set; }
public DateTime EmailSentDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EmailOpenedDate { get; set; }
public Int32 MailFrequency { get; set; }
public DateTime ApprovedDate { get; set; }
public String ApprovedBy { get; set; }
```

I am pretty sure the invalid cast exception is happening on DateTime and Int. Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `CreatedDate = m.Field<DateTime?>("CreatedDate")`? Note that `DateTime?` is not same as `DateTime`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I *think* that should be ok, as you are [allowed](http://share.linqpad.net/f9445g.linq) to set a `DateTime?` to a `DateTime`.

Comment: Do all the fields on the `DataTable` actually match the data type you are trying to pull out of the field? ie. Is `CreatedDate` *really* a `DateTime` and not a `string` that just happens to look like a `DateTime`?

Comment: Based from the target model, seems all property structure matched with data type for every column. However if presented date values stored in DB as `char`, `nvarchar` or `varchar` field, `Field<DateTime>` will throw `InvalidCastException` like this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345996/specified-cast-is-not-valid-linq-datetime.

Comment: I tried with those casting but did not work out.  Even if I comment `CreatedDate`, it happens with the rest!

Comment: Also, for now I am not taking data from DB, I have hardcoded those as `dr["CreatedDate"] = DateTime.Now;` while loading the datatable data

Comment: Try making MailFrequency an "int" instead of "Int32"

Comment: @JacobProffitt well... I had tried that before using Int32! No luck

Comment: Yeah, I realized as soon as I wrote that that Int32 is the same as int...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough creds to comment - so:

Switch to this overload:  [DataColumnCollection.Add (String, Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/730zyedy(v=vs.110).aspx) and specify the type explicitly

The [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52xzw8tf(v=vs.110).aspx) you used tells me:

> By default, the DataType for the new column is string.

That should solve your issue.